# What is the difference between Vuex subscribe and getter?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vuex4

I have a `Product.vue` component that displays product information. It updates whenever the `ProductID` in the route changes with data that is stored in `vuex`. It is done like this:

```
setup() {
...
    // function to trigger loading product into vuex store state
        async function loadProduct() {
          try {
            await $store.dispatch('loadProduct', {ProductID: $route.params.ProductID})
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
        }
    
    // watch the route for changes to the ProductID param and run loadProduct() function above
      watch(() => $route.params.ProductID, async () => {
              if ($route.params.ProductID) {
                loadProduct();
              }
            },
            {
              deep: true,
              immediate: true
            }
        )
    // Get the product data using a getter
        const Product = computed(() => $store.getters.getProduct);
}
```

When I use the above code and go to a route like `localhost:8080/product/123`, the value of `const Product` is empty then after a split second it will have the correct product data. If I then go to another route like `localhost:8080/product/545`, the value of `const Product` will be the old product data of `123` before updating to `545`. This is probably expected behaviour, but it messes up SSR applications which will return to the browser the old data as HTML.

I then came across [`vuex` `subscribe` function](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/api/#subscribe) which solves the problem. But I don't understand *why* or *how* it is different to a `computed` getter. This is the only change required to the code:

```
setup() {
...
  const Product = ref();
  $store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
  Product.value = state.productStore.product
  })
}
```

Now the store is always populated with the new product data before the page is rendered and SSR also gets the correct updated data. Why is this working better/differently to a computed property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`computed()` is Vue internal, and is updated when any `ref` being called inside of it is updated.

`subscribe()` is Vuex specific and will be called whenever **any** mutation was called.

Comment: The question was more about why is `computed()` slower/delayed compared to `subscribe` and why would I not just use `subscribe` over `computed` in every situation

Comment: 1. subscribe is being called right after the mutation, which automatically allows you to update your value directly. While a computed value will update probably just after that. But to be honest this is a guess for now. 2. you do not want to use subscribe over computed because you cant really control which value was changed in your mutation, and every subscription is called on every mutation which makes your code almost like a wonder box with only a few subscriptions.